# Data mining library and license restrictions

Tags: licensing, data-mining, weka

I want realize a data mining service for my customers.
I don't have time to do all the methods of data mining from scratch.
I prefer to use *Weka* for this.

But I don't know:
What will license restrictions been there?
And if I can't using Weka from server-side buisiness application then, what can i use similar *Weka* classlibrary?

Comment: From the [Weka home page](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/): "*Weka is open source software issued under the GNU General Public License*" (version 3 or later it seems).

Comment: I know this, but can I use Weka library in my buisiness app for free?

Comment: If you app is GPL, then you are safe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. See [[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846)] for details, and the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by himself.
I was found this article http://cboblog.typepad.com/cboblog/2008/06/open-source-gpl.html about using GPL on SaaS. Now I understand, which I can use it if library works on server-side only.

Comment: Beware that some applications such as the RapidMiner community edition by now use AGPL, a version of GPL that explicitely includes interaction over the web. I.e. if you make a web application that uses rapidminer on the server (and you don't get the commercial license), then you need to license your application (A)GPL, too.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to **contact them**. They provide professional support via Pentaho, and you can probably get a different license from them. This doesn't necessarily mean it will be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know: What will license restrictions been there?

What a restriction is and what not is in the eye of the beholder. The usage terms are outlined in the license text, so you should read that first. This should answer most of your questions.

The license text should be shipping with the software, and you find commonly asked questions answered on the [GPL FAQ page](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html), too:

- [Does the GPL require that source code of modified versions be posted to the public?](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic)
- [A company is running a modified version of a GPL'ed program on a web site. Does the GPL say they must release their modified sources?](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#UnreleasedMods)

> And if I can't using Weka from server-side buisiness application then, what can i use similar Weka classlibrary?

Weka is free software. You are at least allowed to use it freely, so I do not think you actually need to look for an alternative.